# "England (have/has) been the weaker side..."?

Tags: grammar, american-english

It is written in the online [Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.ps/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/definitely):

> England **have** definitely been the weaker side in the first half of the game.

While Grammarly.com corrected the sentence to:

> England **has** definitely been the weaker side in the first half of the game.

Which version is the correct one?

Comment: You may find the answer in this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119545/country-have-vs-country-has) on ELL, which is a duplicate of another similar one.

Comment: See e.g. *[Is “staff” singular or plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/201939/)*. This simply boils down to whether you interpret *England* to be plural (as representing the members of the team) or singular (the team as a unitary whole). Nowadays, American English almost always treats collective nouns as singular.

Comment: This question comes up about twice a week.